# Running Jupyter Notebook from Docker: curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer

Tags: docker, jupyter-notebook

I have a simple Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN pip install cython jupyter

EXPOSE 8888 4040

CMD ["jupyter", "notebook", "--ip=127.0.0.1", "--port=8888", "--allow-root", "--no-browser"]
```

I build it and launch a container like this:

```
docker container run -d -p 8888:8888 -p 4040:4040 --name test_run my_custom_image
```

Then I check the logs to get the jupyter login token:

```
docker container logs test_run
...
Copy/paste this URL into your browser when you connect for the first time,
    to login with a token:
        http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=7bf22f85e7b942b9936b1403523ba8c334a62bdd278376fc
```

So then I try to curl the link, but I get this:

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:8888/tree?token=7bf22f85e7b942b9936b1403523ba8c334a62bdd278376fc

curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

If I run a `docker container exec -it test_run bash` and run the curl from there, it's working

Running `netstat -tupln` on the host:

```
tcp6       0      0 :::8888                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

Running `netstat -tupln` in the container:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8888          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1/python
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Changed the `--ip=127.0.0.1` to `--ip=0.0.0.0` and it solved my problems..

Comment: Thanks, this was the solution for me too

Comment: Awesome. Thank you! My guess is that the HTTP request is forwarded to the internal docker IP and jupyter refuses it because it only listens to localhost. `0.0.0.0` essentially removes that check (it just means "any IP")